# Определение данных из одной коллекции и вывод в другую mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Есть 2 коллекции. contacts и matchposts

```
const MatchPostSchema = new Schema({
date: String,
day: String,
league: String,
city: String,
stadium: String,
address: String,
contact: String,
ethernet: String,
team_1: String,
team_2: String,
time: String,
commentator: String,
comment: String,
userid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
},
datePosted:{
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
},
```

});

Здесь интересует поле `contact: String`

и коллекция contacts

```
const contactSchema = new Schema({
surname: String,
name: String,
number: String
```

});

Данные в коллекции поступают через `method="POST"`

Эти данные выводятся на другой странице.
Каким образом можно захватить contact из коллекции matchposts, определить что там написано и найти эти данные в коллекции contacts, чтобы выводить на страницу contact из коллекции contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовал делать ссылку вместо строки?

```
contact: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'contact',
},
```

Comment: Вот что получаю на выходе если делаю так
`node:12043) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
(node:12043) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: MatchPost validation failed: contact: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Кирилл Донченко" at path "contact"`

Comment: как монгус должен сопоставить "Кирилл Донченко" с схемой контактов? нужно перебирать данные и исправлять строку на айдишки..

Comment: То есть по вашему мнению человек при вводе данных должен вводить id человека в поле ввода ? 
Вопрос заключается в том как через аггрегатную функцию это реализовать, или инным способом.
На вход подается ФИО, это фио забито уже в другой коллекции. Проблема в том как вытащить из matchposts только ФИО, без лишнего чтобы задать на обработку к другой коллекции

Comment: по моему при вводе данных должна подтягиваться табличка с автодополнением из той схемы с кнопочкой создать новый.

Comment: Спасибо за верхний комментарий, дал правильный путь но чуть изменил.
`type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String`
Получал на вход данные текстовые 
и выполнил поиск так:
`const matchcontact = await (await MatchContact.aggregate([
        { $match: {name: matchpost.contact}},
        { $project: {name: 1}}
    ]))[0]`

Comment: Этот ответ не подходит для галки тогда) но я рад что направил на подходящий путь